# Create a new column on a data frame containing max date for each row

Tags: r

I am currently working on life tables, and I have a data set with 19 columns.Column 5 to column 19 contains the dates 
for each birth an individual had. I want to create a new variable (column 20) which contains the latest birth (last birth) for each row across 5th to 19th column. The data entries belong to factor class.

Here is how my data looks like

```
ID_I        Sex     BirthDate   DeathDate   Parturition1    Parturition2    
501093007   Female  1813-01-14  1859-09-29  1847-11-16      1850-05-17
400707003   Female  1813-01-15  1888-04-14  1844-10-07      1845-10-17
100344004   Female  1813-02-06  1897-05-07  1835-03-09      1837-01-03
```

I have tried the code, suggested in one of the answers;

```
df[, "max"] <- apply(df[, 5:19], 1, max)
```

But I get the overall max across all the rows for the variable df$max. Could it be because my date entries aren't numeric or character?

Comment: Since it sounds like the details of how your data are stored are relevant, please provide an actual sample of your data, e.g. by posting `dput(df[1:3, 1:6])`.

Comment: @Richard Scriven Thank you so much it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, this should work:

```
df$max.date <- apply(df[,5:19],1,max)
```

Comment: the code gave me the overall max across all the rows for the variable df$max.date. My date entries are aren't stored as numeric.

Comment: first, you should convert your date variables to date objects

Comment: even after converting my date variables, the code still gives me the overall max.

Comment: works for me using your data: `data$min.date <- apply(data[,3:6],1,min)`        `data$min.date`
`[1] "1813-01-14" "1813-01-15" "1813-02-06"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example data, we can also use `pmax` after converting to 'Date' class

```
df1$max.date <- do.call(pmax,lapply(df1[3:ncol(df1)], as.Date))
df1$max.date
#[1] "1859-09-29" "1888-04-14" "1897-05-07"
```

NOTE: Change the `3` to `5` in (`3:ncol(df1)`) in the original dataset.

Comment: this code gives me the overall max for all the columns. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: @user5680053 No, it gives the `max` of each row.  If only you check your input data before commenting.